# Can JSON have a boolean root element

Tags: json, spring, junit

One of my teammates wrote a Junit test that follows

```
String userOne = "{\"email\":\"Test@gmail.com\",\"userName\":\"TestSignup\",\"mobileNumber\":\"1234598760\",\"password\":\"Testing\"}";
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/signup")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content(userOne)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$").value("true"))
.andReturn();
```

Is it possible to create a JSON in which the root element is a boolean?

Comment: So your question is if `{ true }` would be valid JSON? Nope, that's not valid.

Comment: However, `[ true ]` is valid json.

Comment: @0stone0 Thank you, sir. I'd informed the team and they modified the test.